# How to apply a function to a tuple?

Tags: scala

This should be an easy one.  How do I apply a function to a tuple in Scala? Viz:

```
scala> def f (i : Int, j : Int) = i + j
f: (Int,Int)Int

scala> val p = (3,4)
p: (Int, Int) = (3,4)

scala> f p
:6: error: missing arguments for method f in object $iw;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       f p
       ^

scala> f _ p
:6: error: value p is not a member of (Int, Int) => Int
       f _ p
           ^

scala> (f _) p
:6: error: value p is not a member of (Int, Int) => Int
       (f _) p
             ^

scala> f(p)
:7: error: wrong number of arguments for method f: (Int,Int)Int
       f(p)
       ^

scala> grr!
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

#### In Scala 2.8 and newer:

```
scala> def f (i : Int, j : Int) = i + j
f: (i: Int,j: Int)Int

// Note the underscore after the f
scala> val ff = f _
ff: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> val fft = ff.tupled
fft: ((Int, Int)) => Int = <function1>
```

#### In Scala 2.7:

```
scala> def f (i : Int, j : Int) = i + j
f: (Int,Int)Int

// Note the underscore after the f
scala> val ff = f _
ff: (Int, Int) => Int = <function>

scala> val fft = Function.tupled(ff)
fft: ((Int, Int)) => Int = <function>
```

Comment: interesting to note, scala (2.11.0 here) will bring your untupled params up to a tuple if you do: `fft.apply(1,2)`

Comment: Good to know you can do this, but this seems not much shorter than just using `function(tup._1,tup._2)` in the first place

Comment: @AllenWang I think the important point is that `tupled` can be used for any arity. Good for maintainability.

Answer (score 18):

Following up on the other answer, one could write (tested with 2.11.4):

```
scala> def f (i: Int, j: Int) = i + j
f: (i: Int, j: Int)Int

scala> val ff = f _
ff: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> val p = (3,4)
p: (Int, Int) = (3,4)

scala> ff.tupled(p)
res0: Int = 7
```

See [def tupled: ((T1, T2)) ⇒ R](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function2@tupled:((T1,T2))=%3ER):

> Creates a tupled version of this function: instead of 2 arguments, it
>   accepts a single [scala.Tuple2](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple2.html) argument.

Answer (score 7):

## Scala 2.13

```
def f (i : Int, j : Int) = i + j

import scala.util.chaining._
(3,4).pipe((f _).tupled)   //res0: Int = 7
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but adding some explanation perhaps could help more people

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> def f (i: Int, j: Int) = i + j
f: (i: Int, j: Int)Int
scala> val p = (3,4)
p: (Int, Int) = (3,4)
scala> val ft = (f _).tupled
ft: ((Int, Int)) => Int = <function1>
scala> ft apply(p)
res0: Int = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

In Scala 3, you can use [`TupledFunction`](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/tupled-function.html):

For a single use, you can do

```
summon[TupledFunction[(Int, Int) => Int, ((Int, Int)) => Int]].tupled(f)((2, 3))
```

To make it easier to use, you can use an extension (copied from Dotty's own documentation)

```
extension [F, T <: Tuple, R](f: F)(using tf: TupledFunction[F, T => R])
  def tupled(t: T): R = tf.tupled(f)(t)
```

And then you can do `f.tupled((2, 3))` to get `5`.