# Invoke a method using a tuple as the parameter list

Tags: scala, syntax, tuples

I wonder what is the best way to do this.

```
val foo = Some("a")
val bar = Some(2)

def baz(a: String, b: Int) = if((b % 2) == 0) Some(a+","+b) else None

(x zip y) flatMap baz //does not compile of course
(x zip y) flatMap { x => baz(x._1, x._2) } //ugly
```

I would presume that Odersky et al. have another trick up theirs sleeve to reduce the noise  in this example.

So the question is how to fight the clutter here assuming you are not allowed to change the implementation of `baz` (e.g. `def baz(a: (String Int))`).

Comment: +1 I know it is kind of a duplicate, but imho the title is way better so it will be found by more people :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This question has already been answered here: [scala tuple unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568002/scala-tuple-unpacking)

First, make foo to a function by partial application, then call `tupled` with your parameter list:

```
(foo _).tupled(myTuple)
```

Comment: Thanks! (x zip y) flatMap (baz _).tupled works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to cleanly unpack anything is with patterns or for-comprehensions:

```
for ((a,b) <- (x zip y); c <- baz(a,b)) yield(c)
```