# What does param: _* mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax, scala-collections

Being new to Scala (2.9.1), I have a `List[Event]` and would like to copy it into a `Queue[Event]`, but the following Syntax yields a `Queue[List[Event]]` instead:

```
val eventQueue = Queue(events)
```

For some reason, the following works:

```
val eventQueue = Queue(events : _*)
```

But I would like to understand what it does, and why it works? I already looked at the signature of the `Queue.apply` function:

```
def apply[A](elems: A*)
```

And I understand why the first attempt doesn't work, but what's the meaning of the second one? What is `:`, and `_*` in this case, and why doesn't the `apply` function just take an `Iterable[A]` ?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`a: A` is type ascription; see [What is the purpose of type ascriptions in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087250/what-is-the-purpose-of-type-ascription-in-scala)

`: _*` is a special instance of type ascription which tells the compiler to treat a single argument of a sequence type as a variable argument sequence, i.e. varargs.

It is completely valid to create a `Queue` using `Queue.apply` that has a single element which is a sequence or iterable, so this is exactly what happens when you give a single `Iterable[A]`.

Comment: so: ¿`a: _*` is like the spread operator of javascript `...a`? beign `a` a collection. You may see spread operator here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 101):

This is a special notation that tells the compiler to pass each element as its own argument, rather than all of it as a single argument. See [here](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html#i-170392618-1).

It is a type annotation that indicates a *sequence argument* and is mentioned as an "exception" to the general rule in section 4.6.2 of the language spec, "Repeated Parameters".

It is useful when a function takes a variable number of arguments, e.g. a function such as `def sum(args: Int*)`, which can be invoked as `sum(1)`, `sum(1,2)` etc. If you have a list such as `xs = List(1,2,3)`, you can't pass `xs` itself, because it is a `List` rather than an `Int`, but you can pass its elements using `sum(xs: _*)`.

Comment: `def sum(xs: _*)` throws 'error: unbound wildcard type'

Comment: Your answer is clear  , but this is actually creating more confusion for me , usually in scala `xs: int` means type of xs is int , going by that is the above a syntax in scala where `xs: _*` means xs is casted to its individual members.

Comment: Followed the above link and looks like thats what it is , type ascription is a scala terminology for java type casting. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: @7kemZmani : You have to define the function with an specific var-args type: `def sum(args: Int*)` and you call it with the wildcard "generic" var-args type: `val a = sum(xs: _*)`. Think about `_*` as "I am passing an Int*, or a String*, or anything* that is defined in the method signature"

Answer (score 23):

For Python folks:

Scala's `_*` operator is more or less the equivalent of Python's [*-operator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

---

**Example**

Converting the scala example from the [link](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html#i-170392618-1) provided by [Luigi Plinge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7938628/1885518):

```
def echo(args: String*) = 
    for (arg <- args) println(arg)

val arr = Array("What's", "up", "doc?")
echo(arr: _*)
```

to Python would look like:

```python
def echo(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print "%s" % arg

arr = ["What's", "up", "doc?"]
echo(*arr)
```

and both give the following output:

> What's
>   up
>   doc?

---

**The Difference: unpacking positional parameters**

While Python's `*`-operator can also deal with unpacking of positional parameters/parameters for fixed-arity functions:

```python
def multiply (x, y):
    return x * y

operands = (2, 4)
multiply(*operands)
```

> 8

Doing the same with Scala:

```
def multiply(x:Int, y:Int) = {
    x * y;
}

val operands = (2, 4)
multiply (operands : _*)
```

will fail:

> not enough arguments for method multiply: (x: Int, y: Int)Int.
>   Unspecified value parameter y.

But it is possible to achieve the same with scala:

```
def multiply(x:Int, y:Int) = {
    x*y;
}

val operands = (2, 4)
multiply _ tupled operands
```

According to [Lorrin Nelson](https://www.lorrin.org/blog/2011/10/04/scalas-missing-splat-operator/) this is how it works:

> The first part, f _, is the syntax for a partially applied function in which none of the arguments have been specified. This works as a mechanism to get a hold of the function object. tupled returns a new function which of arity-1 that takes a single arity-n tuple.

Futher reading:

- [stackoverflow.com - scala tuple unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568002/scala-tuple-unpacking)