# What's the meaning of _*

Tags: scala, syntax

```
val numbers = scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParTrieMap(
    (1 until 100) zip (1 until 100): _*
  ) map { case (k, v) => (k.toDouble, v.toDouble) }
```

For the above code I know that `(1 until 100) zip (1 until 100)` will return something like a Map, but what's the meaning of `_*` following it?

Comment: here check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938585/what-does-param-mean-in-scala

Comment: you can search SO for character n-grams: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scala+%22_%2A%22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling zip method on Range, you are making IndexedSeq structure with of type: `IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)]`. To pass your (Int, Int) tuples into ParTrieMap you have to make a type ascription( your `: _*` annotation), cause you can't pass Seq to ParTrieMap (there is no method with `apply(seq: Seq[(A, B)])` signature defined in ParTrieMap companion object, but there is a `apply(a: (A, B)*)` method). Basically you extract all tuples from Seq and passing them into Map.

Answer (score 5):

Programming in Scala Section 8.8 Repeated parameters has a quick explanation with an example:
_* notation tells compiler to pass each element as its own argument to ParTrieMap

from section 8.8 : 
val arr = Array("What's", "up", "doc?")
when you call

```
echo(arr: _*)
```

it will print

```
What's
up
doc?
```

arr: _* is equivalent to type declaration that tells the compiler to treat "arr" as repeated parameter  e.g. vararg

It's explained well on this [post](http://blog.darevay.com/2009/01/remedial-scala-repeated-parameters-and-initializing-collections/) as well.