# Dataframe: Adding prefix to all columns in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe

```
val prefix = "ABC"
val renamedColumns = df.columns.map(c=> df(c).as(s"$prefix$c"))
val dfNew = df.select(renamedColumns: _*)
```

Hi, 
   I am fairly new to scala and the code above works perfectly to add a prefix to all columns. Can someone please explain the breakdown of how it works ? 
The second line above will return a map of col1 as ABCcol1, col2 as ABCcol2.... etc
I have trouble understanding what the third line is doing , especailly the ":_* at the end.

thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does param: \_\* mean in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938585/what-does-param-mean-in-scala)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The third line is an example of Scala's *syntactic sugar*. Essentially, Scala has ways to shorten just exactly what you are typing, and you have discovered the dreaded `:_*`.

There are two portions to this small bit - the `:` and the `_*` serve two different purposes. The `:` is typically for ascription, which tells the compiler "this is the type that I need to use for this method". The `_*` however, is your type - in Scala this is the type varargs. Varargs is a type that has an arbitrary number of values (good resource [here](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/11/varargs.html)). It allows you to pass a method a list that you do not know the number of elements in.

In your example, you are creating a variable called `renamedColumns` from the columns of your original dataframe, with the new string appendage. Although you may know just how many columns are in your df, Scala does not. When you create dfNew, you are running a select statement on that and passing in your new column names, of which there could be an arbitrary number. 
Essentially, you do not know how many columns you may have, so you pass in your varargs to allow the number to be arbitrary, thus determined by the compiler.