# can you explain this piece of Scala code?

Tags: scala

Can someone please walk through this piece of scala syntax for me? I am new to the language, coming from Java.

```
val map = Map(seq map { a => a.key -> a }: _*)
```

In particular I understand `a => a.key -> a` is an anonymous function that returns a pair(?) `(a.key, a)` for each `a`, but what does `: _*`, `{ }` do and why is there a space between `seq` and `map`? Are they arguments to the `Map` constructor?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938585/what-does-param-mean-in-scala

Comment: for `seq map...` https://stackoverflow.com/a/13011301/497398

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#infix-notation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176440/syntax-sugar-for-treating-seq-as-method-parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`: _*` tells the compiler to pass each element of arr as its own argument to the function, rather than all of it as a single argument. Or to say in other words `it is a special instance of type ascription which tells the compiler to treat a single argument of a sequence type as a variable argument sequence, i.e. varargs`.

The `_*` type annotation is covered in "`4.6.2 Repeated Parameters`" of the SLS.

> > The last value parameter of a parameter section may be sufﬁxed by “*”, e.g. (..., x:T *). The type of such a repeated parameter inside the method is then the sequence type scala.Seq[T]. Methods with repeated parameters T * take a variable number of arguments of type T . That is, if a method m with type (p1 : T1, . . . , pn : Tn,ps : S*)U is applied to arguments (e1, . . . , ek) where k >= n, then m is taken in that application to have type (p1 : T1, . . . , pn : Tn,ps : S, . . . , ps0S)U, with k ¡ n occurrences of type S where any parameter names beyond ps are fresh. The only exception to this rule is if the last argument is marked to be a sequence argument via a _* type annotation. If m above is applied to arguments (e1, . . . , en,e0 : _*), then the type of m in that application is taken to be (p1 : T1, . . . , pn : Tn,ps :scala.Seq[S])

`{ }` indicates a `block of code`, which is composed of `multiple statements` and `declarations`, and whose value is that of the last statement. If you need declarations, multiple statements, an import or anything like that, you need curly braces

Scala has a special `punctuation-free` syntax for invoking methods that take one argument. General rule is `Scala methods that take a single parameter can be invoked without dots or parentheses`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ramesh's answer.. your seq is most likely a Scala collection. Scala collections have numerous methods like map, filter, fold, reduce etc etc. So map is a method call on seq which is called without using the dot operator. This is allowed in Scala iff the method takes a single parameter.
The _* is somewhat weirder. Immutable Map requires a vararg as parameter. But the map method on seq will return a Map. The _* is in position of "type". By type, I simply mean, if I write i: Int, so Int is the type. So when an object's type is marked as _*, automatic type conversion takes place by the compiler which uses a factory to convert the object into a vararg. Like in Java, varargs can only appear as last parameter in a parameter list.