# Replacing the parameters of a function with a vector

Tags: scala, argument-unpacking

In Scala, if I have a function f(X, Y, Z) is it possible to pass a variable W that will represent (X, Y, Z) so I can use f(W) instead of f(X,Y,Z)? If so, how can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Scala equivalent of the Python list unpack (a.k.a. "\*") operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034565/is-there-a-scala-equivalent-of-the-python-list-unpack-a-k-a-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean to pass a **tuple** or **case class** instead of the three parameters. Then yes, you can.

First, If it is a **function**, you can just: `f.tupled(tuple)`.
If it is a **method** then: `(m _).tupled(tuple)`. _(it is basically the same, but using eta-expansion to turn the method into a function).

If you have a **case class** instead of a tuple, you can to turn an instance of it into a tuple with this: `W.unapply(w).get` *(where `W` is the companion object of the case class, and `w` is the instance)*.