# Function only has uncurried - Scala?

Tags: scala, function, currying

I am studying the curried function of Scala but encountered the following question.

```
scala> def add(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
add: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> val addCurried = Function.curried(add _)
<console>:11: error: value curried is not a member of object Function
       val addCurried = Function.curried(add _)

scala> val addCurried = (add _).curried
addCurried: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>
```

Then, I looked into Scala's API ([Function](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Function$)) and found that the object `Function` does not have the method `curried`. However, according to this post ([Function Currying in Scala](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala)), it should work.

On the other hand, I also tried to transfer a curried function into un-curried one:

```
scala> def adder(x:Int)(y:Int): Int = x + y
adder: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int

scala> val addUncurried = Function.uncurried(adder _)
addUncurried: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> val addUncurried = (adder _).uncurried
<console>:11: error: value uncurried is not a member of Int => (Int => Int)
       val addUncurried = (adder _).uncurried
```

In this case, because `uncurried` is a member of `Function`, `Function.uncurried(adder _)` is working. But this `(adder _).uncurried` is not working instead.

Can anyone explain why it is designed like this in Scala? And

Comment: You are looking at the post from 2008. Find something newer. Curried has been deprecated 6 years ago already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568002/scala-tuple-unpacking