# How to apply tuple to a format string in Scala?

Tags: scala

### Edit1

I have already seen this question: [Applying a function to a tuple in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987820/applying-a-function-to-a-tuple-in-scala)

Ideally I would simply like to do like this:

```
scala> val t = ("A", "B", "C")
t: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) = (A,B,C)

scala> "%-10s %-50s %s".format(t) // or some closer syntax
```

Which should give output as

```
res12: String = A          B                                                  C
```

### Edit2

Or in some sense Scala complier should be able to infer that I am actually calling with correct arguments and types such that

`"%-10s %-50s %s".format(t.untuple)` expands to `"%-10s %-50s %s".format(t._1, t._2, t._3)`

Can I use a macro to do this?

### Original question follows

I have a tuple which I use for formatting a string:

```
scala> val t = ("A", "B", "C")
t: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) = (A,B,C)

scala> "%-10s %-50s %s".format(t.productElements.toList: _*)
warning: there were 1 deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
res10: String = A          B                                                  C

scala> "%-10s %-50s %s".format(t._1, t._2, t._3)
res11: String = A          B                                                  C
```

All works fine till now. But this fails:

```
scala> val f = "%-10s %-50s %s".format(_)
f: Any* => String = <function1>

scala> f(t.productElements.toList: _*)
warning: there were 1 deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '-50s'
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2487)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2423)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2797)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.format(StringLike.scala:270)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.format(StringOps.scala:31)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:7)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:7)
    at .<init>(<console>:10)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:704)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$14.apply(IMain.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:43)
    at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

This also fails:

```
scala> f.apply(t)
java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '-50s'
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2487)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2423)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2797)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.format(StringLike.scala:270)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.format(StringOps.scala:31)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:7)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:7)
    at .<init>(<console>:10)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:704)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$14.apply(IMain.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:43)
    at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I apply tuple parameters to a "varagrs" style function?

Comment: May I ask why you need to use a `tuple` for formatting? Why not using other approaches? For example [String interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) which is a clean way to make interpolated strings from some values.

Comment: I know that I can use string interpolation. I only want to use string formatter. Wth string interpolation syntax I would have to use underscores for tuple which are somewhat ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in lambda definition

`val f = "%-10s %-50s %s".format(_)`

is equivalent to:

`val f = x => ("%-10s %-50s %s".format)(x)`,

So you're just passing sequence as first argument here.

Correct lambda is:  `(x: Seq[Any]) => ("%-10s %-50s %s".format)(x: _*)` or even just `val f: Seq[Any] => String = "%-10s %-50s %s".format`

Examples:

```
scala> val f = x => ("%-10s %-50s %s".format)(x)
f: Seq[Any] => String = <function1>

scala> f(Seq(1,2,3))
java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '-50s'

scala> val f: Seq[Any] => String = "%-10s %-50s %s".format
f: Seq[Any] => String = <function1>

scala> f(Seq(1,2,3))
res75: String = 1          2                                                  3
```

Unfortunately scala don't understand `("%-10s %-50s %s".format)(_: _*)`, so you can't use underscore.

What's interesting here: if you try to do same using underscore without apply - you won't have to specify _* explicitly:

```
scala> val f = ("%-10s %-50s %s": scala.collection.immutable.StringLike[_]).format _
f: Seq[Any] => String = <function1>

scala> f(Seq(1,2,3))
res81: String = 1          2                                                  3
```

But you have to specify type class explicitly because `function _` construction [doesn't work with implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470320/why-function-construction-doesnt-work-with-implicitly-added-members).

Comment: However this is still not a typesafe way as I hoped it to be. All members of the Tuple get converted to `Any`.

Comment: `format` function itself typed as `Any*`, so you have to accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can define `f` as follows:

```
def f(t: Product) = "%-10s %-50s %s".format(t.productIterator.toList: _*)
```

then you can apply it to `t`:

```
scala> f(t)
res1: String = A          B                                                  C
```

### What is `Product`

`scala.Product` is a `trait` which is implemented by many classes, for example `Product2` and `Product3`. These classes in turn are super types of `Tuple2` and `Tuple3` respectively.

So briefly, any tuple is a `Product`. That's why `productIterator` is available on all tuples.

So in order to use a tuple as vararg one way is to use the `productIterator` and convert it to `List` by invoking the `toList` method.

### A better signature

Maybe the following signature is a better signature for your function:

```
 def f(fmt: String)(t:Product) = fmt(t.productIterator.toList: _*)
```

Now you can apply (or partially apply) it to get the desired result :

```
val res = f("%-10s %-50s %s")(t)
val newFormatter = f("%-10s %-40s %s")_
val newResult = newFormatter(t)
```

Comment: Note that you can put the `f` function in an arbitrary class and rename it to `format`, then provide an implicit conversion from String to that class. Then, by importing that implicit conversion and enabling implicit conversions, you can call the format method on strings and pass it a tuple like this: `"%s".format(tuple)`