# Why eta-expansion doesn't work with implicitly added members

Tags: scala, functional-programming, typeclass

This doesn't work:

```
"%-10s %-50s %s".format _
<console>:13: error: missing arguments for method format in trait StringLike;
 follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
          "%-10s %-50s %s".format _
```

But this works:

```
import scala.collection.immutable._

scala> ("%-10s %-50s %s": StringLike[_]).format _
res91: Seq[Any] => String = <function1>
```

So, why i have to specify type class explicitly?

Comment: `"%-10s %-50s %s".format(_)` also works

Comment: it's not the same - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469071/how-to-apply-tuple-to-a-format-string-in-scala/26469868#26469868

Comment: format(_) will give you function from one parameter, even if it's actually _*. in turn, `format _`  is not bound to the count of arguments.

Comment: It's better if you post the whole code, I mean those parts concerning the "implicitly added members".

Comment: The whole code are in scala library :). Strings are implicitly converted to the StringLike. format is a part of StringLike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8299

That's not a whole lotta why.

Not sure if this needs saying, but:

```
scala> val f: Seq[Any] => String = "%-10s %-50s %s".format
f: Seq[Any] => String = <function1>
```

Comment: when i'm asking such questions i usually have a feeling like the answer is some SI-XXXX :)