# How to chain function arguments in Scala?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'd like to define my tests using the following function (ignore some dependencies for now e.g. `fixture1` etc they are at the bottom):

```
multiTest("my test name", fixture1) { case (x: Double, y: Int, z: String) =>
   // test body
}
```

and `multiTest` is defined in my base custom `FunSpecLike` subclass as:

```
def multiTest(testName: String, fixture: FixtureTable)(fun: => Unit)(implicit pos: source.Position): Unit = {
    val heading = fixture.heading
    fixture.values.foreach { tuple =>
        it(autoGenerateDesc(heading, tuple)) {
            fun tuple // <<<<<< how can I pass the tuple to the definition above?
        }
    }
}
```

How can I push the tuple to the function?

Some of the missing pieces are:

```
case class FixtureTable(heading: Map[String, String], values: Seq[Any])
// tableFor generates the permutations of all paramater values 
val fixture1 : FixtureTable = tableFor(
  ("x", List(1e-1, 1e-2)),
  ("y", List(1, 2, 3)),
  ("z", List("a", "b")))
```

Comment: does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987820/how-to-apply-a-function-to-a-tuple

Comment: Not sure how ... can you provide an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, you can't. Change `multitest` to

```
def multiTest(testName: String, fixture: FixtureTable)(fun: Any => Unit)(implicit pos: source.Position): Unit = {
    val heading = fixture.heading
    fixture.values.foreach { tuple =>
        it(autoGenerateDesc(heading, tuple)) {
            fun(tuple)
        }
    }
}
```

or even better

```
case class FixtureTable[A](heading: Map[String, String], values: Seq[A])
def multiTest[A](testName: String, fixture: FixtureTable[A])(fun: A => Unit)(implicit pos: source.Position): Unit = {
    val heading = fixture.heading
    fixture.values.foreach { tuple =>
        it(autoGenerateDesc(heading, tuple)) {
            fun(tuple)
        }
    }
}
```

but it would be harder to write the `tableFor` function for this case.