# How to get rid of the "non-variable type argument Type in type pattern (Type, Type) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure"?

Tags: scala

I'm working in a project that uses Scala 2.10 and I have this code that uses an expanded or annonymous function e.g.

```
multiTest("Tarn to Mc", fixture1) {
   case (capRaw: (Double, Int), /* .. more arguments .. */ callPut: Tuple2[Double, Double]) =>
   // test body implementation
}
```

for both cases above I get the warning:

```
non-variable type argument Double in type pattern (Double, Int) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

How can I get rid of this warning without having to define my own class UDTs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
multiTest("Tarn to Mc", fixture1) {
   case ((d: Double, i: Int), /* .. more arguments .. */ callPut: Tuple2[Double, Double]) =>
   // test body implementation
}
```

This might remove the compilation warning.

Answer (score 1):

While Barrameda's answer is entirely reasonable, you can often do better by allowing the compiler to check the types itself. It [looks like you went with the first solution to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744322/how-to-chain-function-arguments-in-scala), but if you use the second one with

```
case class FixtureTable[A](heading: Map[String, String], values: Seq[A])
def multiTest[A](testName: String, fixture: FixtureTable[A])(fun: A => Unit)(implicit pos: source.Position): Unit = ...
```

you wouldn't get the warning, because the compiler already knows `capRaw` has type `(Double, Int)` and doesn't need to insert a check (and of course, for the same reason you can just write `case capRaw =>` without the type).

Comment: Hahaha good inter-Q catch ... since everything is working now I will pospone doing what you propose but I will try to implement your proposed cleaner solution. However, as you pointed out before it is hard to implement the generic cross product using the template parameter. For now I simply use `Product` instead of `[A]`