# How to use zip and map to create zipwith function to Array in scala

Tags: scala

I tried to use `zip` and `map` to create `zipwith` function like:

`def zipWithArray(f : (Int, Int) => Int)(xs : Array[Int], ys: Array[Int]) : Array[Int] = xs zip ys map f`

But I got the following compile error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int) => Int
 required: ((Int, Int)) => ?
```

I know the `zip` is `(Array[Int], Array[Int])=>Array((Int, Int))`, so the `f` should be `(Int, Int) => Int` and the total result is `Array[Int]`. Could anyone help to explain the case please. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(Int, Int) => Int` is function which takes two `Int` as argument.
`((Int, Int)) => ?` is function which takes one tuple which consists of two `Int` as argument.

Since `xs zip ys` is array of tuple, what you need is function which takes tuple as argument and returns `Int`.

So `xz zip ys map f.tupled` should work.

Reference: [How to apply a function to a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987820/how-to-apply-a-function-to-a-tuple)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much as the error message states; change your function signature to:

```
def zipWithArray(f : ((Int, Int)) => Int)(xs : Array[Int], ys: Array[Int])
```

Without the extra parentheses, `f` looks like a function that takes two integers, rather than a function that takes a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the function to accept  arguments as tuples and then map can be used to call the function.
For example :

```
scala> def add(a : Int, b: Int) : Int = a + b
add: (a: Int, b: Int)Int

scala> val addTuple = add _ tupled
<console>:12: warning: postfix operator tupled should be enabled
by making the implicit value scala.language.postfixOps visible.
This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import scala.language.postfixOps'
or by setting the compiler option -language:postfixOps.
See the Scaladoc for value scala.language.postfixOps for a discussion
why the feature should be explicitly enabled.
       val addTuple = add _ tupled
                            ^
addTuple: ((Int, Int)) => Int = scala.Function2$$Lambda$224/1945604815@63f855b

scala> val array = Array((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
array: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))

scala> val addArray = array.map(addTuple)
addArray: Array[Int] = Array(3, 7, 11)
```